# How do I access $q (promise service) from this angular ajax service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have the following angular service:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function ($http) {
    var returnedObject = {
        getA: function() { return $http.get('../A'); },
        getB: function() { return $http.get('../B'); },
        getC: function() { return $http.get('../C'); },
    };

    return returnedObject;
});
app.controller('MyService', MyController);
```

I want to execute a function when all services complete like so:

```
    $q.all([
        returnedObject.getA().success,
        returnedObject.getB.success,
        returnedObject.getC.success,
    ]).then(function () {
        console.log("promise kept");
    });
```

I'm just not sure where I can find $q. I'm confused by all the indirection. I'm looking to basically do what was suggested in this question.

Comment: replace all `returnedObject.getA().success,` by just `returnedObject.getA()` - `$http.get()` will return promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just "ask for it" in your function arguments:

```
app.factory('myFactory', function ($http, $q) {
```

google "Angular Dependency Injection" for more info

Comment: In case you're confused - what's happening here is that angular is finding out what parameter to pass based on the argument name.

Comment: Wow mind blown! That's so non intuitive. Will try soon.

Comment: yeah, it's really an "odd" pattern, and if you're minifying your app it actually breaks and you have to define the arguments separately so that they're not lost.

Answer (score -1):

Every getFunction should return an promice that $q do.

```
getA: function() { 
  $http.get('../A').then(function(res){ 
     return res;
  });
 }
```

And then you can call $q.all()

```
$q.all([
     getA(),
     getB()
   ]).then(function(data) {
     var a = data[0];
     var b = data[1];
    deferred.resolve(a+b);
  });
```

Do not forget to inject $q as dependency to your service

Comment: There is no need to wrap `$http.get` call in such weird way - `$http.get` will return promise itself, and if you need only data from response - you can add `than` right after `get(...)` and return `response.data` from it (`than` from promise will also return a promise)

Comment: Adding to what @BogdanSavluk said, this is called the [deferred anti pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-anti-pattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Comment: @paka not exactly - `return res.data`, or just remove this `than` call - now it is useless...